# i get - Error: Entry not found in cache - during sls deploy

Tags: node.js, azure, serverless

I create basic azure nodejs template with serverless

```
serverless create --template azure-nodejs --name azure-crud
```

after that i don't change nothing in the code, and to try the basic things i run

```
sls deploy
```

but when i run this command i get this error in the cmd

```
Serverless: Initializing provider configuration...
Serverless: Configuration warning: Unrecognized provider 'azure'
Serverless:
Serverless: You're relying on provider plugin which doesn't provide a validation schema for its config.
Serverless: Please report the issue at its bug tracker linking: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/plugins#extending-validation-schema
Serverless: You may turn off this message with "configValidationMode: off" setting
Serverless:
Serverless: Parsing Azure Functions Bindings.json...
Serverless: Parsing Azure Functions Bindings.json...
Serverless: Building binding for function: hello event: httpTrigger
Serverless: Building binding for function: goodbye event: httpTrigger
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Logging into Azure
Serverless: Using subscription ID: xxx
Serverless: Creating resource group: some-resource-group

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: Entry not found in cache.
```

and it cancels the deploy process. What should i do to make this things work ?  Where is the problem ?

i have this sls version

```
Framework Core: 1.80.0
Plugin: 3.8.1
SDK: 2.3.1
Components: 2.34.9
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late but delete the `~/.azure/slsTokenCache.json` file worked for me